# Troubles with React Router v5

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to display a settings page within a user profile that has multiple routes within it such as My account, change password, etc...)

The default layout for the /settings page shows on /settings but the subsequent pages (/settings/account, /settings/change-password) refuse to show. I've been trying to troubleshoot this for a couple hours and can't seem to come up with a solution...

**Index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(attemptGetUser())
      .then(() => setLoading(false))
      .catch(() => setLoading(false));
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return loading ? (
    <Loading cover="page" />
  ) : (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Views} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Views/index.js**

```
export const Views = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/auth">
        <AuthLayout />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/">
        <AppLayout />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Views);
```

**AppViews/index.js**

```
const AppViews = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading cover="content" />}>
      <Switch>
        <ProtectedRoute path={`/dashboard`} component={Dashboard} />
        <ProtectedRoute path={`/settings`} component={Settings} />
        <ProtectedRoute path={`/logout`} component={Logout} />
        <Redirect from={`${match.url}`} to={'/dashboard'} />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default AppViews;
```

**Settings/index.js**

```
const SettingOption = ({ match, location }) => {
  return (
    <Menu
      defaultSelectedKeys={`${match.url}/account`}
      mode="inline"
      selectedKeys={[location.pathname]}
    >
      <Menu.Item key={`${match.url}/account`}>
        <UserOutlined />
        <span>My Account</span>
        <Link to={`account`} />
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key={`${match.url}/change-password`}>
        <LockOutlined />
        <span>Change Password</span>
        <Link to={`change-password`} />
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  );
};

const SettingContent = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      {/* <Redirect exact from={`${match.url}`} to={`${match.url}/account`} /> */}
      <Route path={`${match.url}/account`} component={EditProfile} />
      <Route path={`${match.url}/change-password`} component={ChangePassword} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export class Setting extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <InnerAppLayout
        sideContentWidth={320}
        sideContent={<SettingOption {...this.props} />}
        mainContent={<SettingContent {...this.props} />}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Setting;
```

**ProtectedRoute**

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ path, component }) => {
  const { isAuth } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  return isAuth ? (
    <Route path={path} exact component={component} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/auth/login" />
  );
};
```

Any help is much appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `exact` on your route at `AppViews/index.js`

```
<ProtectedRoute exact path={`/settings`} component={Settings} />
```

and also subsequent route at `Settings/index.js`

```
<Route exact path={`${match.url}/account`} component={EditProfile} />
<Route exact path={`${match.url}/change-password`} component={ChangePassword} />
```

Comment: On the Settings/index.js routes? I’ve done that to no avail

Comment: try to use `exact`  on setting route too at `AppViews/index.js`

Comment: I did that, and when going to `/settings/account` it redirects me to `/dashboard`. It's almost like that `<Switch>` isn't being recognized in `Settings/index.js`

Comment: its probably happens b/c of the logic inside the `ProtectedRoute` component, can you share that please to check what happens  inside of t hat component ?

Comment: its because of this line {/* <Redirect exact from={`${match.url}`} to={`${match.url}/account`} /> */}

Comment: remove that  and you done ! or you can uncomment that and put it below two setting routes

Comment: Removing that didn't do anything, i've updated the OP with the `ProtectedRoute` component code

Comment: can you log the `isAuth` value to see what it logs to the console?, but i think that its because of the redirect line that you've wrote there b/c as you said it redirects you to the /dashboard

Comment: The console displays `true`

Comment: check where do you redirect user to the `/dashboard` route , also there check inside of `EditProfile ` component

Comment: The redirect to `/dashboard` occurs in the `Views/index.js` file. In the `EditProfile` component there is nothing but `<h1>Edit Profile</h1>` in the return statement